# Bootstrap Modal Freezes iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

**Environment**

- I have an `iframe` that throws up a `bootstrap 2.3.2 modal`.
- The modal closes fine and passes back control to the `iframe` nicely if the finish button is clicked.
- If the modal pops up and then user then clicks somewhere off the modal, the modal disappears as I expect and the gray disappears from the screen.
- But the `iframe` is frozen and I can no longer click on any buttons or enter text in any field as usual.

**Question**

- Why does this happen?
- Can I get back to the `iframe` without refreshing?  That would be undesirable as that `iframe` contains data I need to save.

Comment: Can you provide a working example of the issue via jsFiddle or similar?

Comment: I will definitely try and recreate it in a fiddle and post here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it was something that had to do with focus.  I had to add the following script inside my iFrame to regain focus.  Adding the respective code in the parent window did not seem to fix it, but this did the trick in my iframe:

```
        $('#myModal', parent.document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        debugger;
        var iframe = $("#myIframe")[0];
        iframe.contentWindow.focus();
    });
```